# jquery command works successfully on console but does not work when click() is added but doesn't show any errors either

Tags: javascript, jquery

Go to this page :  [CNET Login](https://www.cnet.com/user/login/?appId=376)

Using jquery I'm trying to click on the facebook button that's just above the Google+ button. (see the three buttons on the left)

On the Chrome developer console, I type in the following and it works :

```
$('#rbContent > div > form > div.social-authenticate > ul > li.social-site.facebook > span')
```

I add in click() like so :

```
$('#rbContent > div > form > div.social-authenticate > ul > li.social-site.facebook > span').click()
```

and the console shows it is successful (or at least looks like it) but the nothing happens on the browser itself. It's as if the click was not triggered at all.

Screenshot of both those options here :

[image]

Comment: so they must be looking for an event or something.... Did you look to see what they are actually doing with the click?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Had to workaround it.  Here's the java version of the implementation for the google button (not fb). (you can do the same thing in js as well)

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//*    [@id='rbContent']/div/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/span"))));
WebElement googleLogin = driver.findElement (By.xpath("//*[@id='rbContent']/div/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/span"))   ;


Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(googleLogin).click().perform();
```